# Navigate from one html page to another but keep them in memory both

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Normally, html navigation will release the first html page and load another.
But I hope to navigate from one html page to another but keep them in memory both, thus I can apply the document messages.

Is it possible?

Welcome any comment.

Comment: You should consider Using Jquery `Load`

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

No, you cannot change page and keep the old page in memory.

Yes, you can store the current window.document into a variable and then over-write the entire page with content loaded via AJAX from another page.

This method won't really load the new page though. The url will be the same, the title will be unchanged, really only the DOM will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use tabs

http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/target.en.html#tab1

Putting your contentent for each page in a separate tab div and play with the formatting / navigation to simulate moving between pages to make it look to the user they are navigating pages but are really tabbing through a single page.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use messages (onmessage, postMessage), you can do that with frames, iframes to be specific. One parent window with two iframe windows and they can talk to each other (also over different domains, so the Same Origin Policy doesn't apply) utilizing onmessege and postMessege. If the two iframes dont load a page from the same domain, you will not be able to access the window/DOM